# SSAS tabular project connection issue - memSQL DB as data source

Tags: ssas, tabular, singlestore

I am trying to create a SSAS tabular project where data source is memSQL DB. I am able to connect to the memSQL database from any SQL client tool using MySQL and/or MariaDb OBDC driver. But when I am using the same ODBC driver for a SSAS tabular project "using OLEDB provider for ODBC" then I am getting error like below:

```
    Failed to retrieve data from DATE_DIM. Reason: ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver][mysqld-5.5.58]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*
  FROM [DATE_DIM]' at line 1

ERROR [42000] [ma-3.0.9][5.5.58]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*
  FROM [DATE_DIM]' at line 1
```

I have used the connect string as "`Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;DSN=memSQLDB`". Test connection was successful, but when trying to preview any table's data it throws the above error to me.

Is it a compatibility issue between memSQL (5.5.58) version and MySQL ODBC driver (version-5.3) or MariaDB OBDC driver (version-3.0.9)?

Can anyone suggest if there is any compatible ODBC driver exists, which can work with SSAS ?

Answer (score 0):

With this error message, it appears it's less about authenticating correctly and more about the SSAS tool issuing queries with syntax MemSQL doesn't understand.  Can you grab the query(ies) and post them here?  That'll help us migrate these to compatible syntax.  Depending on how the tool works, you may not have control over changing these queries, and will need the tool vendor to patch the query syntax to be more compatible.

Comment: We had a chat with Microsoft support and they confirmed we have to use SSAS version 2017 onward. We are trying to get version 2019. Hopefully problem will be resolved.

Comment: Sounds great. Glad upgrading the tool will solve the issue.